# How to display correct value on toolitp?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which assign value to toolip, which seem to work somewhat. only problem i am having is when i mouse over say **Home** it shows the last mousedover "**music**" instead of the current mouseover.

How can I show the correct text on mouse over

**JS**

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {

       $(".nav#menu span ").mouseover(function() {
            var Val = $(this).html();
            console.log("spanVal "+Val)
            $(".nav#menu li a").attr('data-original-title',Val);
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
        })
    });
```

**HTML**

```html
    <div ng-controller="" ng-Click="">
      <ul class="nav" id="menu">
        <li>
          <a class="toggle-button-on" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title=""><i class="fa fa-exchange">toggle</i></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="Home" ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="">
            <i class="fa fa-home fa-3x">fa </i>
            <span>Home</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="">
            <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-3x">fa </i>
            <span>Work </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="Music" ng-class="" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="">
            <i class="fa fa-table fa-3x">fa </i>
            <span>Scenario <br/>Music</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a ui-sref="faq" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="">
            <i class="fa fa-faq fa-3x">fa </i> 
            <span>Faq</span> 
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are declaring your id in your html using `id="#menu"` instead of `id="menu"` (without the `#`)

But here is how I would do it anyway:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

   $("#menu span").on('mouseover', function() {
        var Val = $(this).html();
        console.log("spanVal" + Val);
        $(this).parent().attr('data-original-title',Val);
        $('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    });

});
```

**[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vc1ht1ve/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".nav#menu span ").mouseover(function() {
        var Val = $(this).html();
        console.log("spanVal "+Val)
        $(this).parent().attr('data-original-title',Val);
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    })
});
```